# Buffered Read line on reads the first line

Tags: java, file, cryptography, buffered

I am writing a program that decrypts a text file that has been encrypted.
My buffered reader only seems to read the first line of the text file only?
This is shown by my decryption function() only printing out the first line only correctly decrypted.
I have attached a snippet of my code but im not sure where it is going wrong.
The b variable is to exhaustively decrypt the code, its irrelevant to the file reading

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("decryptthis.txt"));
    String message;
    while (((message = br.readLine()) != null))
    {
        message = message.toUpperCase();
        while (b <= 26)
        {
            decryption(message, b);
            b++;
        }
```

This part is in my main function

```
public static String decryption(String message, int b)
```

This is what my decryption function takes in

i think i need it to go in loop and continuously feed my decryption function the lines, however i thought this was done by the != null part

Any help would be appreciated it.
Thank you

Comment: What is the `b` variable used for?

Comment: You are saying that "b" its irrelevant to the file reading while the 'reading' stops after b goes higher than 26

Comment: the b is the intercept for my decryption function, it does not affect my reading file

Comment: please have a look at how to write a [MCVE]

Comment: Please quote the code to the end of the first while statement.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to put the correct code lines to the corresponding methods.
Your problem is not located at the 'reading' part. How to confirm that? Just print what lines your buffer reads. After that, call your decryption method that inside includes all the decrypt codes.

For example,

```
final var path = Paths.get("PathToYourTxt");

try (var lines = Files.lines(path)) 
{
    lines.forEach(System.out::println);
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this will print the content of the txt. (check it)

In your case,

```
final var path = Paths.get("PathToYourTxt");

try (var lines = Files.lines(path)) 
{
    lines.forEach(line -> decryption(line));
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void decryption(String message) 
{
    // put your code here with all your checks with that B variable
}
```

Each method is doing something. Try not to stop your reading. Just abort the strings on your method with your conditions